# search form works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search-box

I have a page that displays list of boxes, when i search once it gives me the result perfectly, when i search again, nothing is shown at all

SEARCH BOX:

```
<form class="search-form">
  <input type="text" id="searchfield" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="mybox">
    <div data-title="Titleshoudbehere" class="myitem">
      <a target="_blank">

        <div class="mytitle">
          <p>Title is here</p>

        </div>

        <div class="footer">
          <p>#hashtag </p>
        </div>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.search-form').on('submit', function() {
  return false;
});


$('.search-form .btn').on('click', function(e) {
  var query = $.trim($(this).prevAll('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase();
  $('div.mybox .mytitle').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1)
       $this.closest('div.col-md-4.col-sm-6').fadeOut();
    else   $this.closest('div.col-md-4.col-sm-6').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: Where is the element with the `event-title` class?

Comment: @Jeto my bad, pls check again

Answer (score 1):

I've just copy-pasted your code into a snippet and it seems to work fine.

Try typing "Title" and then typing "Foo", and then "Title" again for instance:

```js
$('.search-form').on('submit', function() {
  return false;
});


$('.search-form .btn').on('click', function(e) {
  var query = $.trim($(this).prevAll('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase();
  $('div.mybox .mytitle').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1)
      $this.closest('div.mybox').fadeOut();
    else $this.closest('div.mybox').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search-form">
  <input type="text" id="searchfield" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="mybox">
    <div data-title="Titleshoudbehere" class="myitem">
      <a target="_blank">

        <div class="mytitle">
          <p>Title is here</p>

        </div>

        <div class="footer">
          <p>#hashtag </p>
        </div>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i changes it to be $this.closest('div.col-md-4.col-sm-6').fadeOut(); so that the divs don't consume space . it's not working but your run does work :(

Comment: @YaraBinSaif Yeah that change works too (no reason it shouldn't). Did you try adding some `console.log`'s to try and figure out what is happening?

Comment: where should i add exactly?

Comment: i added    console.log(query); to check whether the value of query is right and it appears fine

Comment: @YaraBinSaif Well on your event handlers for a start. Do they trigger at all? In any case, you'll have to find the difference between what you posted here and your actual code.

Comment: yes it triggers, the function works when the user clicks search. it's just that the result shows only on the first search, when i try to search something else it doesn't even though the console.log(query) is showing the right word

Comment: i just notices that when i change it back to $this.closest('div.mybox').fadeOut(); it works, but the problem is that the divs consume space

Comment: Well go further then, `console.log($this.text().toLowerCase())`, `console.log($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query))`, etc.

Comment: pls check my last comment

Comment: @YaraBinSaif Please update your code with the version that isn't working (with `div.col-md-4.col-sm-6` if I understood correctly).

Comment: i almost know why it's not giving me results. i have a loadmore button, and the problem is that it only gives search result of what is already displayed on the screen. so complicated

Comment: so if i search for something that contains "5th", when i search again for something, the search will be through the first result only, it will search in the divs in my last result only:(